# How to Pass Position of RecyclerView to Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, cardview

I am trying to pass position of recyclerview to another activity where I am calliing retrofit Interface. Can I pass position of Recyclerview item so I can load different post from api

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TagAdapter.Tag_ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tagName.setText(Tags.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (position < 8){
                int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), Tag1Post.class);
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

My EndPoint is

```
@GET("/tag/{id}/")
Call<Tag> test(@Path("id") int id);
```

I want to replace id by RecyclerView position.

Comment: Why `int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1`  rather than `position` .

Comment: RecyclerView Position start from 0 and API id start from 1

Comment: Oh ,got it.So is there any problem with your code?

Comment: I don't know is there problem or not. I am here to seek help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the position of Recycler View I pass the id of the particular post to navigate to comment on that post.

**1. Provide Intent Extra with id of clicked post on Bindview holder of Adapter**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.postTitle.setText(posts.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.postBody.setText(posts.get(position).getBody());
        setAnimation(holder.itemView);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = posts.get(position).getId(); // get Id
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CommentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("pos", id); // Pass Id
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

**2. Retrieve passed intent data**

```
int mPostId = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);
```

**3. Pass retrieved data to the retrofit endpoints**

```
Call<List<Comment>> call = apiService.getComments(mPostId);
```

Retrofit Endpoints

```
@GET("/posts/{id}/comments/")
    Call<List<Comment>> getComments(@Path("id") int id);
```

I hope this will help someone to encounter this type of problems.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interface then transfer the position from the adapter to the activity.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (position < 8){
                int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent (view.getContext(), Tag1Post.class);
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                //create your interface in Activity, then send it to adapter and call it here:
                yourListener.onTransferPosition(position);
            }
        }
```

On your activity that implements interface:

```
 public void onTransferPosition(int position) {
    this.position= position;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the view position using Intent class you can simply get the position in your second activity as below

```
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
```

Or you can pass value using a interface

```
  public interface OnRecyclerClickListener  {
    void makeRestCall(int position);
}
```

Instantiate the interface as follow

```
onRecyclerClickListener  = (OnRecyclerClick) this.mContext;
```

send the view position like below

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (position < 8){
            int  pos = (int) getItemId(position) + 1;
            startActivity(new Intent (view.getContext(), Tag1Post.class));
            onRecyclerClickListener.makeRestCall(pos);    
        }
    }
```

Finally, implement interface in your second activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRecyclerClickListener{

@Override
public void makeRestCall(int pos) {
   // do your GET request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnClickListener;
```

Use this in your Adapter and ask this from your constructor.

```
Adapter(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onClickListener){
this.mOnClickListener=onClickListener;
}
```

in your onclick method in holder class do like this:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mOnClickListener.onItemClick(null, view, getAdapterPosition(), view.getId());
        }
```

And implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` in you activity

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                 // here you will get the postion of the clicked item
    }
```